# Measure Theory - understanding usage of Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Tags: convergence-divergence

I am trying to understand the given proof below. But I don't really understand how the Theorem of Dominated convergence is applied?

[image: dfv]

Which is the function that "dominates" the sequence? and we need to know that this funcion is Lebesgue integrable. There is no such function (explicitly) given.

Comment: As $f$ is bounded there is a number $M$ such that $|f(x)|\le M$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Use the constant function $\varphi(x)=M$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ as your dominating function.